# Can other users see my starred/bookmarked/favorited posts?

Tags: support, bookmarks

I was wondering whether other users can see my Stack Exchange Site starred/bookmarked/favorited posts (i.e. are these public or private), and if so where can these be seen. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your favourite choices are not considered private. Anybody can see the choices [you](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2610873/john-sonderson?tab=favorites) or [I](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1038015/robert-longson?tab=favorites) have made.

Comment: More than that: it's even possible to see all favorites from all sites in one place: http://stackexchange.com/users/3083067/john-sonderson?tab=favorites